# Errors in Setting JavaScript Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, adobe-brackets

I am placing a cookie to stop showing an offensive jokes warning alert if someone has already seen it but Adobe Brackets is showing 51 problems and 1 error and my JavaScript is not up to scratch.  Don't worry the cookie will not be used in identifying users and I have a cookie policy showing.

code below is there any way I can clear the error and problems. I have placed 100% of the code and the errors Brackets had identified following this.

Error is ESLint terminated with error:timeout

```
function writeCookie(name, value, hours) 
{}
function readCookie(name)
{}
function alert1()
{}

function writeCookie(name, value, hours)
{
    var expire = ""; 
    if(hours != null)
    {
        expire = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + hours * 3600000);
        expire = "; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expire;
}

function readCookie(name)
{
    var cookieValue,offset = "";
    var search = name + "=";
    if(document.cookie.length > 0)
    { 
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1)
        {
            offset += search.length;
            end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
            if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
            cookieValue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function alert1()
{
    var seen = readCookie("viewed"); 
    if(seen !== "yes") 
    { 
        if(confirm("***WARNING*** \n Some of these jokes MAY be offensive. \n  \n If you do not wish to be offended \n Please Press Cancel to return \n \Please note this will place a cookie on your computer"))
        {
            writeCookie("viewed", "yes", 9999); 
        }
        else 
        {
            window.location="index.htm" 
        }
    }
}
```

Problems as per brackets

1
Unexpected '(space)'.   function writeCookie(name, value, hours)
2
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {}
2
Expected '{' at column 5, not column 1. {}
2
Missing 'use strict' statement. {}
4
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {}
4
Expected '{' at column 5, not column 1. {}
4
Missing 'use strict' statement. {}
6
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {}
6
Expected '{' at column 5, not column 1. {}
6
Missing 'use strict' statement. {}
9
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {
9
Expected '{' at column 5, not column 1. {
10
Missing 'use strict' statement. var expire = "";
10
Expected 'var' at column 9, not column 5.   var expire = "";
10
Unexpected '(space)'.   var expire = "";
11
Expected 'if' at column 9, not column 5.    if(hours != null)
11
Expected exactly one space between 'if' and '('.    if(hours != null)
11
Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.    if(hours != null)
12
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {
12
Expected '{' at column 13, not column 5.    {
13
Expected 'expire' at column 17, not column 9.   expire = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + hours * 3600000);
14
Expected 'expire' at column 17, not column 9.   expire = "; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
15
Expected '}' at column 13, not column 5.    }
16
Expected 'document' at column 9, not column 5.  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expire;
16
'escape' was used before it was defined.    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expire;
17
Expected '}' at column 5, not column 1. }
20
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {
20
Expected '{' at column 5, not column 1. {
21
Missing 'use strict' statement. var cookieValue,offset = "";
21
Expected 'var' at column 9, not column 5.   var cookieValue,offset = "";
21
Missing space between ',' and 'offset'. var cookieValue,offset = "";
21
Missing space between ',' and 'offset'. var cookieValue,offset = "";
22
Expected 'var' at column 9, not column 5.   var search = name + "=";
22
Combine this with the previous 'var' statement. var search = name + "=";
23
Expected 'if' at column 9, not column 5.    if(document.cookie.length > 0)
23
Expected exactly one space between 'if' and '('.    if(document.cookie.length > 0)
24
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {
24
Expected '{' at column 13, not column 5.    {
24
Unexpected '(space)'.   {
25
Expected 'offset' at column 17, not column 9.   offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search);
26
Expected 'if' at column 17, not column 9.   if (offset != -1)
26
Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.    if (offset != -1)
27
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. {
27
Expected '{' at column 21, not column 9.    {
28
Expected 'offset' at column 25, not column 13.  offset += search.length;
29
Expected 'end' at column 25, not column 13. end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
29
'end' was used before it was defined.   end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
30
Expected 'if' at column 25, not column 13.  if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
30
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.    if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
30
Expected '{' and instead saw 'end'. if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
30
Too many errors. (57% scanned). if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;

Comment: LocalStorage is much more appropriate for this. Cookes are sent to servers and back, and you clearly don’t need that here so use the appropriate solution. Also: please format your code and errors to be more legible. And most of what you printed are just somebody else’s idea of correctly linted code. Correct for them, but mostly bs rules that make no difference.

Comment: These are all just code style warnings -- notice that lots of them are about whitespace and column numbers.